# Couldn't open SQL Server database view on my machine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a problem while running SQL Server 2012 on my machine.

I installed SQL Server 2012 on my machine but just show it

1. SQL Server Configuration icon
2. Import and export data icon
3. SQL Server installation icon
4. SQL Server Error and usage icon.

There I can't see SQL Server 2012 Management Studio icon, so I wasn't able to view the database and tables in it.

Please guide me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you install **Sql Server Management Studio 2012**? You have to install it.
You can download the management tools from the below link

[**Microsoft SQL Server SP 1**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579)

Select only **SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe** or **SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe** from the download options.